# Closest distance Vector

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the value of $t$ for which the vector
$v = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -3 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ 5 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} t$ is closest to
$a = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}.$

I know I definitely need to used projections to solve this. However, how do I use projections here when one of the vectors is a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Solve the equation $$[\pmatrix{2\\-3\\-3}+\pmatrix{7\\5\\-1}t-\pmatrix{4\\4\\5}]\pmatrix{7\\5\\-1}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

As you noted $v$ is a straight line and the point of this line closest to $A=(4,4,5)$ is the intersection between the line and the orthogonal plane to this line passing through $A$. The equation of this plane is:
$$
\begin {bmatrix}
x-4\\
y-4\\
z-5\\
\end{bmatrix}
[7,5,-1]=0
$$
Substitute the coordinates $x,y,z$ with a point on the line: $(2+7t,-3+5t,3-t)$ and find $t$.

This is the same as Peter answer, but I hope you can understand where it come from.